# Что не так в настройке 301-редиректа на главное www-зеркало сайта?

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

Если кратко, то проблема выглядит следующим образом:

- Имеется главное зеркало сайта с www — https://www.pozdravunchik.ru,
- на которое корректно срабатывает перенаправление с http http://www.pozdravunchik.ru и http://pozdravunchik.ru,
- но не срабатывает редирект с https без www https://pozdravunchik.ru.

Просьба взглянуть и подсказать, где допущена ошибка в настройке редиректов?

**Настройки в htaccess**:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).pozdravunchik.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.pozdravunchik.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.pozdravunchik.ru/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www.pozdravunchik.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.pozdravunchik.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www.pozdravunchik.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pozdravunchik.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Настройки переадресации внутри конфигурационного файла в /etc/nginx/ следующие**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pozdravunchik.ru;
    
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.pozdravunchik.ru ;
    
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.pozdravunchik.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.pozdravunchik.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    server_name  pozdravunchik.ru;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.pozdravunchik.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.pozdravunchik.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    server_name www.pozdravunchik.ru ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как выяснилось, ssl-сертификат был выпущен только для www-поддомена. В этом и была проблема. С настройками переадресации всё нормально. Корректный перевыпуск сертификата решил проблему.